# Переход между активити с общими элементами

Tags: android, android-animation, transition

Приветствую, реализуя Transition animation  столкнулся вот с такой проблемой:

Есть два активити с общими элементами которые при переходе анимируются одновременно. Есть ли возможность установить задержку для каждого элемента?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

анимация для для MainActivity:

```
    Fade fadeTransition = new Fade();
    fadeTransition.setDuration(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.anim_duration_medium));

    TransitionSet transitionSet = new TransitionSet();
    Slide slide = new Slide();
    slide.setDuration(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.anim_duration_slide));
    slide.setSlideEdge(Gravity.TOP);
    slide.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
    slide.excludeTarget(R.id.titleAnimationTransition, true);
    slide.excludeTarget(R.id.toolbar, true);

    Fade fade = new Fade();
    fade.setDuration(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.anim_duration_medium));
    fade.setStartDelay(DELAY);

    transitionSet.setInterpolator(new LinearOutSlowInInterpolator());
    transitionSet.addTransition(fade);
    transitionSet.addTransition(slide);

    getWindow().setReenterTransition(fadeTransition);
    getWindow().setExitTransition(transitionSet);
```

анимация для detailActivity:

```
final TransitionSet transitionSet = new TransitionSet();
transitionSet.setPathMotion(new ArcMotion());

// anim Image
ChangeBounds changeBounds = new ChangeBounds();
changeBounds.setDuration(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.anim_duration_long));
changeBounds.setStartDelay(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.anim_duration_startDelay));
ChangeBounds changeBoundsText = new ChangeBounds();

// anim Text
changeBoundsText.setDuration(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.anim_duration_long));
transitionSet.addTransition(changeBounds);
transitionSet.addTransition(changeBoundsText);
getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(transitionSet);
```